# Issues with timing for Angular RSS reader project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some issues with a college/personal project. Full script is here: http://pastebin.com/w3iGwzTc

The `data` from the `getFeed` function contains a JavaScript object with RSS data. The `$scope.savedStories` is attached to an ng-repeat element and the data *is* being passed to it because the elements are being created. However the console.log before and after comes up as *`[]`* in the console and the for loop doesn't fire as the `$scope.savedStories` is empty.

I feel it might be something to do with timings but it should be in that scope.

```
getFeed().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data, 'this defintely should have some data in it');
    $scope.savedStories = data;
    console.log($scope.savedStories, 'This one?');
    for (var story in $scope.savedStories){
      console.log(story, ' - Sending for summary...')
      getSummarisation($scope.savedStories[story]).then(function(data) {
        $scope.savedStories[story].image = data.image;
      }); 
    }
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
});
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: What is `getFeed?` is that using Angular's `$http` service or is it otherwise included in the `$digest` cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I just looked at your code, `getFeed()` is processed outside the `$scope.$digest()` cycle.

Instead, you should use the `$http` service (or an abstracted service that uses `$http`) to make sure that your logic is happening inside of Angular's digest process. Generally, it's not a good idea to mix AngularJS and jQuery.